# Using contains returns too many results

Tags: xpath

In the html below, I'm trying to get the two nodes that contain values for `shipment_number`, but instead I get 6 `<td>` nodes - why? Doesn't `contains` limit the nodes to only those that match the text value? If so the statement below should only return two, not six?

In Chrome dev console:

```
$x("//tr//td[contains(.,'shipment number')]/following::td[1]")
```

[image]

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Date</td>
                                                <td>11/15/2019</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>shipment number</td>
                                                <td>abc_123_florida-45</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Departure time:</td>
                                                <td>0430</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Time arrival</td>
                                                <td>1715</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>customer</td>
                                                <td>bob smith</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>box type</td>
                                                <td>square</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr name="laneStop">
                                <td>box1</td>
                                <td>23.45</td>
                                <td>lane1</td>
                                <td>south</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr name="laneStop">
                                <td>box2</td>
                                <td>17.14</td>
                                <td>lane1</td>
                                <td>south</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr name="laneStop">
                                <td>box3</td>
                                <td>17.18</td>
                                <td>lane1</td>
                                <td>north</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr name="laneStop">
                                <td>box2</td>
                                <td>199.14</td>
                                <td>lane1</td>
                                <td>west</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Date</td>
                                                <td>11/16/2019</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>shipment number</td>
                                                <td>abc_222_florida-35</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Departure time:</td>
                                                <td>0630</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Time arrival</td>
                                                <td>1715</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>customer</td>
                                                <td>sue smith</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>box type</td>
                                                <td>rect</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr name="laneStop">
                                <td>box1</td>
                                <td>33.45</td>
                                <td>lane1</td>
                                <td>south</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr name="laneStop">
                                <td>box2</td>
                                <td>1.14</td>
                                <td>lane1</td>
                                <td>south</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr name="laneStop">
                                <td>box3</td>
                                <td>27.18</td>
                                <td>lane1</td>
                                <td>north</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr name="laneStop">
                                <td>box2</td>
                                <td>299.14</td>
                                <td>lane1</td>
                                <td>west</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
//tr//td[contains(text(),'shipment number')]/following::td[1]
```

That's because `contains(., '...')` converts `.` to string by expanding all its text descendants, not just children.

Comment: thats it, thank you.  thant makes sense, the way I was doing it was comparing apples to oranges.  getting the text of the node first makes sense instead of just getting the node

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this answer because `text()` node test might conflict with others requirements, mainly those dealing with inline markup.

The reason because you are getting six `td` elements is that there is six `td` having `"shipment number"` as part of theirs string value (concatenation of all descendant text nodes). And that is because you have nested tables, thus nested `td` elements. So, you want a `td` element not having a descendant `td` element.

The expression:

```
//tr//td[not(.//td)][contains(.,'shipment number')]/following::td[1]
```

It selects:

```
<td>abc_123_florida-45</td>

<td>abc_222_florida-35</td>
```

Check in http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/37bd889231ad68bb7bfa377433aeca00

**Do note** that your input sample has a default namespace declaration with the namespace URI `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`. Because niether your code sample nor your selected answer are ussing namespaces, I asume you know how to work with them.